# How Many Nodes Are Involved in a Match

Tags: neo4j, cypher

How can I know how many nodes and edges are involved in a MATCH? Is there another way besides Explain / Profile Match?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean how many nodes are matched in a path, such as a variable-length path, then you can [assign a path variable](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/match/#named-paths) for this:

```
MATCH p = (k:Person {name:'Keanu Reeves'})-[*..8]-(t:Person {name:'Tom Hanks'})
WITH p LIMIT 1
RETURN p, length(p) as pathLength, length(p) + 1 as numberOfNodesInPath
```

You can also use `nodes(p)` and `relationships(p)` to get the collection of nodes and relationships that make up the path, and you can use `size()` on those collections to get their size.

Answer (score 0):

There exists the `COUNT()` function of Cypher that allows you to count the number of elements. As for example in this query:

```
MATCH (n)
RETURN COUNT(n);
```

This query will count all nodes in your database.

You can find more information in the cypher manual, under the aggregating functions. [Check it out.](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/aggregating/#functions-count)

Comment: Sorry, I did not explain it right.

There is another way to count the resolved nodes and edges in a MATCH query. Besides PROFILE MATCH or EXPLAIN MATCH?

Answer (score 0):

The following Cypher snippet should return the number of distinct nodes and relationships found by any given `MATCH` clause. Just replace `<your code here>` with your `MATCH` pattern.

```
MATCH <your code here>
WITH COLLECT(NODES(p)) AS ns, SUM(SIZE(RELATIONSHIPS(p))) AS relCount
UNWIND ns AS nodeList
UNWIND nodeList AS node
RETURN COUNT(DISTINCT node) AS nodeCount, relCount;
```